# How add revision number svn in tgz file?

Tags: svn, npm, package.json

I need to add the svn revision number to my tgz file when I package my Angular app.

I create the script version  in package.json but I don't know how replace the name of tgz generated by npm pack.

```
{
  "name": "apps",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Angular WorkSpace",
  "scripts": {
   "version": "ng build myfolder --prod && cd dist/myfolder  && npm pack && svn info --show-item last-changed-revision ???? ",
}
```